# ReactJS front-end with NodeJS backend: Rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm currently making an application  using ReactJS for the front-end and NodeJS for the backend, however, I'm confused regarding how to connect those two. 
I read about both, server-side rendering and client-side rendering.
I followed this tutorial (https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/ ) as to how to connect my ReactJS app, which I created using creat-react-app and my node backend, however, I read that the solution of adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"` (or whatever port node runs on) to the package.json file is only suitable for development.
Anyway, what I would like to know is: What is the best way of connecting ReactJS and Node.js if the user should be able to enter,delete or update data, which is saved to a database?

Comment: You can use express.js or egg.js for back-end.

Comment: @Cecil that's what I'm doing (I should've mentioned that) but my problem is that I don't really understand how I'm supposed to connect the front-end to the backend. I'm not sure the way I'm handling it right now is particularly suitable and how it is going to work once the application is in production

Comment: You will have to provide some kind of an api that your react app can post to and fetch data from. Most common is a so called REST api. This not special to react or node. Every client-server-application needs it.

Comment: Forget about server side rendering for the moment. It has nothing to do with connecting server and client. This is just a way to provide an initially rendered page to the client, e.g. to allow crawlers of search engines like google to analyse your page or to reduce initial loading times. It can not replace an api for communication.

Comment: @A.S.J The first method is that the back end provides only the data interface (API), the front end only render the page, and the back end data interface is invoked in the page. The second way is that you can also use the template engine to render the pages in express and egg. It is recommended to use the first method.

Comment: @Cecil could you link me to examples of both methods so I could better understand the differences/ so I can read more about method 1? Up until now I only read about how to set up the backend with express.

Comment: @A.S.J https://github.com/Cecilxx/egg-pinellia used the first method

Comment: thank you very much! Unfortunately, I can't quite follow what was done in this example, so basically you are saying I should do it like it was done here (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bNlffXEcC0) rather than here(https://blog.cloudboost.io/creating-your-first-mern-stack-application-b6604d12e4d3)? Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @trixn I already set up a REST api using node/express, however my problem is that I feel as if I'm not connecting the front-end to the api properly since I added a proxy-key in my package.json file in my client folder (client folder is located in my root directory) and I read that that's only fine for development so I wasn't sure if that was correct. For reference, I structured the whole application kind of like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bNlffXEcC0

Comment: In your production configuration you have to update the package.json with the URL where your Node.js backend will be deployed: `"proxy": "http://[PRODUCTION_URL]:[PRODUCTION:PORT]"`.

Comment: @Dez but I did that. I was mainly confused because, after using `express my-folder-name` there were different routes in route folder that rendered `.jade`-files and I thought I had to render the React-files like that as well (I thought I had to render the html-file with the root-element this way)

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/). It is based on React and NodeJS.

I believe this is exactly what you are looking for. It is an easy-to-use framework that handles all the difficult stuff when it comes to server rendering while keeping the frontend async and dynamic. Besides that. When you get better using it, you can do in dept configuration to optimize to you need. Hope that helps.

Try out one of the examples on the git repository.